# Python - MS SQL run multiple queries without losing previous queries

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to automate some of my routine tasks using MS SQL and Python. 
Any help is appreciated!

I was trying to use pyodbc to do so. I have to access multiple databases in a single MS SQL server. And here is roughly what I wish to do.

```
select col1, col2, col3 into #temp1 from db1.table1
select col4, col5, col6 into #temp2 from db2.table2
select a.*, b.* into #final from #temp1 a join #temp2 b on a.col1 = b.col 4
```

But, what happens when I try to run this sequential code in python is. It fails to refer to previous temporary tables.

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Don't use temporary tables.  Just write a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single query instead of using several temporary tables.

Like :

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4, b.col5, b.col6
from db1.table1
join db2.table2 on a.col1 = b.col 4
```

PS : most likely you don't need to return `col4` from the query, as you know for sure that it has the same value as `col1` (because that's how you joined the two tables).

Answer (score 0):

You are using local temp tables, they are only accessible within the same session. You may use global temp tables, use ## instead of #, but don’t forget to drop them

Comment: For this solution, make sure to run all queries in a single connection (spid). Even global temp tables do not persist beyond the spid. Or as MS puts it in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - "Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them."